# How to use print statement to debug function executed in partition

Tags: python, pyspark

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sparkobj as spk

from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest

def train_forest_per_partition_map_step(partition):
    print('partition')
    print(partition)
    get_data = np.asarray(list(partition))
    assert get_data.shape[1] == 2
    return [IsolationForest(n_estimators=100,
                            contamination=0.15,
                            random_state=666).fit(get_data)]

def main():
    spark = spk.getsparkobj()
    n_samples = 300
    outliers_fraction = 0.15
    n_outliers = int(outliers_fraction * n_samples)
    n_inliers = n_samples - n_outliers
    rng = np.random.RandomState(666)

    data = pd.DataFrame(data=np.concatenate([make_blobs(centers=[[0, 0], columns=["feat_1", "feat_2"]) # skipping some unrelevant

    df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data)
    df = df.rdd.repartition(numPartitions=3).toDF()
    forest = df.rdd.mapPartitions(f=train_forest_per_partition_map_step).collect()
    lines = df.rdd.collect().foreach(println)

    # Reduce step: Combine scores from partitions.
    forest[0].decision_function(data) # Partition 1 Isolation forest.
    forest[1].decision_function(data) # Partition 2 Isolation forest.
    forest[2].decision_function(data) # Partition 3 Isolation forest.       

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Is there a way to get the print results in the function "train_forest_per_partition_map_step" after the partitions has been executed? I have tried df.rdd.collect().foreach(println) but keep getting attribute error

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'foreach'
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
in engine
      1 if __name__ == '__main__':
----> 2     main()

<ipython-input-1-c5cff78d4b35> in main()
     25 
     26     forest = df.rdd.mapPartitions(f=train_forest_per_partition_map_step).collect()
---> 27     lines  = df.rdd.take(100).foreach(println)
     28     
     29     # Reduce step: Combine scores from partitions.

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'foreach'
```

Guess that's only available for scala but would like to know the Python equivalent

Comment: Do you want to print the line `print(partition)` in your function `train_forest_per_partition_map_step`?

Comment: @mayank agrawal thanks for helping out! yes, that's what I want to do mainly to debug the function train_forest_per_partition_map_step

Answer (score 0):

Instead of print go for **`show,collect,count`** methods. This will make the process execute at that very point

```
df.show()
df.filter("your_clause").collect()
df.count()
```

Let me know if this is what you were looking for

Comment: thanks for help out! would you mind share some example that I can try within the function?